# I am trying to calculate the charge of the following electric circuit after an infinite amount of time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image: Electric circuit]

The answer is apparently Q=2/3CV. I have tried equating the UR potential with the 3UR and UC but haven't succeeded to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with DC sources, at infinity time the capacitor will behave as an open circuit. Therefore, if you remove it from the circuit, you will have a circuit with two loops. Let $I_A$ be the current loop of the loop with the four resistors and $I_B$ the current for the loop with the voltage source, both currents in counterclockwise directions. Using mesh analysis, we build the system
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 4R & -R \\ -R & R \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} I_A \\ I_B \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ V \end{array} \right)
$$

Solving this system you get $I_A = V / 3R$. Now the voltage drop on the capacitor will be $V_C = 2RI_A = 2V/3$. Thus, the charge is
$$
Q = CV_C = \dfrac{2}{3}CV
$$

Comment: You can make the solution even simpler by ignoring the resistor that is directly across the voltage source.

Comment: @relayman357 Absolutely!